# Matching Bootstrap Grid Rows w/jQuery_matchHeight for jq novice

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web design and trying to teach myself at home. I've started to get a very basic grasp of simple html, css. I'm trying to code a site using the Bootstrap css. However on one page I want columns to sit side by side 3x2 and 2x3 with equal size containers. I have seen a few different options, one I want to try is using a jQuery file called matchHeight. I can't get it to work, probably because I was hoping to avoid using any js as I haven't learned didly about it.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(div).matchHeight(byRow);
    $('.box').matchHeight();
});
```

```css
.box {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
       
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce , tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
 
</div><!-- close container -->
 
 
<!-- nav footer -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom">

  <div class="container-footer">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">+33 (0) 6 27 38 56 46</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">massage@progressionski.com</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="fblink">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ProgressionPhysiotherapyMassageFirstAid/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x pull-right"></a> <!-- nav foot right items FB #x2 -->
    </div><!-- close fblink -->

  </div><!-- close container -->
</nav><!-- close nav footer -->

<!-- Javascript files should be linked at the bottom of the page -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jquery equal height fix for column rows -->
<script src="js/jquery.matchHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[screenshot probably incorrect code to Activate matchHeight js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPSDF.jpg)

[jfiddle result from hannesbelen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5widv.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Bootstrap, you should keep in mind that the direct child div of a container div should be a row div. When looking at your JS code, you make two easy-to-spot mistakes. The first one is passing `div` as an argument instead of `'div'`. The second one is that there's no need to call the matchHeight method twice, since you are only trying to make one type of html element have the same height.

Take a look at this JSFiddle for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/a5qmqjjs/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I wasn't sure if I needed to add <div row> after container because of the way each xs sm md will change using the grid system. I've checked the changes you've suggested and they haven't made the <div box>'s the same height.  It could be that I'm not applying the jQuery properly. It's new to me as of yesterday, I was trying to just use html and css for my first attempt.

Comment: Could you explain what part of the jsfiddle that I provided doesn't function as intended? The height of the `.box` elements that are displayed in the same row have the same height, which is what I thought you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Yeah that is what I wanted, I've just opened the jfiddle link you gave, expanded the result screen and the rows are still out of line therefore presumably still different heights. On the jfiddle page are the columns aligned when you enlarge the result screen so it's 3 columns x 2 rows?

Comment: Yes they are. If your question is solved, you can tag this question as the correct answer. Happy to help!

Comment: Side by side, all together in neat rows. Because when I hit the jfiddle link you sent me they're still all staggered. I'm confused as to why your link is showing me something different to what you're seeing

Comment: Your `.box` element headings all start on the same height, which is an indication that the `.box` elements themselves have the same height. You can right click and inspect the elements and check their heights yourself. All the boxes that occupy the same row have the same height, which is the exact behaviour that you are looking for. I am not sure what you mean with 'staggered'.

Comment: I've added a screenshot at the end of my question, that shows what I'm seeing in the jfiddle result you sent me. For some reason it's staggered

Comment: It's because you typed `calls='box'` instead of `class='box'` in your html. Fixing this fixes your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/8do1ykad/.

Comment: If this answer completely solves your problem, you can tag this answer as the correct one.

Comment: Thank You for attempting to help resolve my problem, but it hasn't corrected it. I'm going to leave this question as unanswered, and change the layout to something simpler that fits my ability, or lack of ;)

Comment: hannesbelen - your answer was absolutely right, I did not think it had worked because I was expecting the img to vertically align on the bottom of each div +1 to you, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any other dev noobs like me stumble across this, I finally found where I was going wrong. Firstly, yes, I had not applied jQuery `matchHeight` script correctly.
When I applied it correctly, I discovered that the column heights were still uneven. After days of trying different CSS commands which were all unsuccessful, it dawned on that I had 2 Text and 1 image elements all in the same `DIV`. Once I split the text and img into separate `DIV`s, it all aligned properly :)

```
    <!-- open row -->
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="boxtext">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>ADD SOME BIG SHOUTY CAPITALS. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        </div><!-- close boxtext -->
                            <div class="boximg">
                            <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </div><!-- close boximg -->
                    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="boxtext">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boximg">
                            <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </div><!-- close boximg -->
                    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="boxtext">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boximg">    
                            <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </div><!-- close boximg -->
                    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="boxtext">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boximg">
                            <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </div><!-- close boximg -->
                    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="boxtext">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>Add a little text. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boximg">
                            <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </div><!-- close boximg -->
                    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="boxtext">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>What about down here? Is it aligned. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        </div><!-- close boxtext -->
                        <div class="boximg">
                            <img src="http://www.wellbeingguide.net/wp-content/uploads/home-physiotherapy-1024x683-720x480.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </div><!-- close boximg -->
                    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            </div><!-- close row -->            

        </div><!-- close container -->
```

As you can see I've given the text a class of boxtext and the img a class of boximg, this was purely so I could apply matchHeight to them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $('.boxtext').matchHeight();
  });   

  jQuery(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $('.boximg').matchHeight();
  });   
</script>
```

This should work without using any CSS